# Are there any existing 360° panoramic photo libraries?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, panoramas, virtual-tour

We're starting a web application where we would like to implement virtual-tours of the most relevant parts of our university. For this we would most likely use 360° panoramic photos. The idea is to show the photos and add information over them ( I.E: markers, links, videos)

Now I have been looking for libraries in order to implement the application. For now it seems the best option to achieve virtual tours is to use Flash or Flex, still I wanted to ask wich ones are the best libraries to render 360 panoramic photos, and if there are any libraries implemented in other languages like Java or c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PanoSalado 2](http://os.ivrpa.org/panosalado/) is probably the most used.  It's been around for awhile, works well, and is reasonably well documented.

Comment: Do you know of any examples showing how to use it?. I have been searching for them however I just found the api documentation.

Comment: Have a look at [Frank Dürr's Panosalado Viewer](http://www.frank-durr.de/panosalado2.html).